# Lua: Merge 2 strings collections in a case-insensitive manner

Tags: lua

I want to merge two strings collections in a case-insensitive manner:

```
string_collection1 = {"hello","buddy","world","ciao"}
string_collection2 = {"Hello","Buddy","holly","Bye", "bYe"}
merged_string_collection = merge_case_insensitive(string_collection1,string_collection2) --> {"hello","buddy","world","holly","bye","ciao"}
```

Here's an attempt, but it does not work...

```
function merge_case_insensitive(t1,t2)
    t3 = {}
    for _,s1 in pairs(t1) do
        for _,s2 in pairs(t2) do
            if string.lower(s1) == string.lower(s2) then
                t3[s1] = s1
            end
        end
    end
    t4 = {}
    i = 1
    for s,_ in pairs(t3) do
        t4[i] = string.lower(s)
        i = i + 1
    end
    return t4
end

string_collection1 = {"hello","buddy","world","ciao"}
string_collection2 = {"Hello","Buddy","holly","Bye", "bYe"}
merged_string_collection = merge_case_insensitive(string_collection1,string_collection2)

for k,v in pairs(merged_string_collection) do print(k,v) end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you use == to compare both strings which is case-sensitive.

You could do something like `string.lower(s1) == string.lower(s2)` to fix that.

Edit:

As you can't figure out the rest yourself, here's some code:

```
local t1 = {"hello","buddy","world","ciao"}
local t2 = {"Hello","Buddy","holly","Bye", "bYe"}

local aux_table = {}
local merged_table = {}

for k,v in pairs(t1) do
  aux_table[v:lower()] = true
end

for k,v in pairs(t2) do
  aux_table[v:lower()] = true
end

for k,v in pairs(aux_table) do
  table.insert(merged_table, k)
end
```

`merged_table` now contains the lower case version of every word in both input tables.

Now pour that into a function that takes any number of input tables and you are done.

What we did here:  we use the lower case version of every word in those tables and store them in a list. `aux_table[string.lower("Hello")]` will index the same value as `aux_table[string.lower("hello")]`. So we end up with one entry for each word, even if a word comes in multiple variations.
Using the keys saves us the hassle of comparing strings and distiguishing between unique words and others.

Comment: yes of course. you only add the words to the output if they exist in both tables. simply remove the if statement and use the words as lower case keys in the result table. I thought I'd leave you something to think.

Comment: Consider using `ipairs`, or a numeric loop, when iterating on array-like tables.

Comment: @oka and why would I do that?

Comment: @Piglet Good habit, and is the proper function for the job. Keeps order in other contexts, where that might be important.

Comment: @Oka and what if his word list becomes a bit more complicated, maybe  containing a gap? then you are screwed. 
my good habit is only to use ipairs when I'm 100% sure I won't have any gaps or non-numeric keys. it's just too error prone. and what makes it the "proper function" here?

Answer (score 1):

To get a table with all strings from two other tables appearing once (without regard to case), you need something like this:

```
function merge_case_insensitive(t1,t2)
  local ans = {}
  for _,v in pairs(t1) do ans[v:lower()] = true end
  for _,v in pairs(t2) do ans[v:lower()] = true end
  return ans
end

string_collection1 = {"hello","buddy","world","ciao"}
string_collection2 = {"Hello","Buddy","holly","Bye", "bYe"}
merged_string_collection = merge_case_insensitive(string_collection1,string_collection2)

for k in pairs(merged_string_collection) do print(k) end
```

Edit: And in case you want an array result (without adding another iteration)

```
function merge_case_insensitive(t1,t2)
  local ans = {}
  local
  function add(t)
    for _,v in pairs(t) do
      v = v:lower()
      if ans[v] == nil then ans[#ans+1] = v end
      ans[v] = true
    end
  end
  add(t1)
  add(t2)
  return ans
end

string_collection1 = {"hello","buddy","world","ciao"}
string_collection2 = {"Hello","Buddy","holly","Bye", "bYe"}
merged_string_collection = merge_case_insensitive(string_collection1,string_collection2)

for _,v in ipairs(merged_string_collection) do print(v) end
```

Comment: Added it, just in case.  No extra iteration needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by simply iterations over both tables, and storing a temporary dictionary for checking what words we have already found, and if not there yet, putting them in our new array:

```
function Merge(t1, t2)
    local found = {} --Temporary dictionary
    local new = {} --New array
    local low --Value to store low versions of words in later
    for i,v in ipairs(t1) do --Begin iterating over table one
        low = v:lower()
        if not found[low] then --If not found yet
            new[#new+1] = low --Put it in the new table
            found[low] = true --Add it to found
        end
    end
    for i,v in ipairs(t2) do --Repeat with table 2
        low = v:lower()
        if not found[low] then
            new[#new+1] = low
            found[low] = true
        end
    end
    return new --Return the new array
end
```

This method eliminates the need for a third iteration, like in Piglet's answer, and doesn't keep redefining a function and closure and calling them like in tonypdmtr's answer.